# How to set a field's 'translatable' property

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n

When I create a new field type in Drupal it seems to be automatically assigned a 'translatable' property and it's not always right. For example, I would expect a Long Text field type to be marked as translatable = TRUE, but for some reason it's coming in as FALSE sometimes. However, body is TRUE.

Is there a place where this property is exposed in the UI and changeable?

I have the i18n module installed and enabled.

Answer (score 2):

[Entity translation](http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation) exposes a checkbox which allows to set the translatable property.

It also provides a user interface to actually use field translation, there isn't much you can do with translatable fields without that module anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
function mymodule_field_available_languages_alter(&$languages, $context) {
  $languages = array();
}
```

The hook is documented in [Multilingual Field API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.multilingual.inc/group/field_language/7), and [hook_field_available_languages_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_available_languages_alter/7).

*somehow i18n does not respect that ..*

Comment: A bit late, but i18n is not supposed to respect this. I18n doesn't care about field level translatability, it translates complete nodes. What it provides as an alternative is i18n_sync, which allows to keep certain fields in sync between node translations.